# Using "hardly" and "no sooner" constructions

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

I have got one task on translation:

> 1. They'd hardly come into the house when the storm broke out.
> 2. Hardly had he opened the window when the strong wind scattered the papers on the floor.
> 3. I had hardly reach (had approached) the corner of the street when I heard someone's steps behind me.
> 4. Hardly had I said good-bye to them when the train started moving.

Although constructions "hardly" and "no sooner" both almost have the same meaning, they are slightly different in meaning (when we are translating them), and as a result it would be better not to use "no sooner" instead of "hardly" in the sentences above.

Am I right?

Comment: *No sooner* implies greater immediacy than *hardly* but which you used would simply be a matter of preference.

Comment: No sooner and Hardly can be used to suggest that one thing happened very soon after another.(Often with the past perfect tense)
Both of the meaning seem identical .

Comment: @Ronald Sole: I'm not convinced ***no sooner*** implies greater immediacy - I think it's just becoming increasingly *dated* by comparison with ***just***. So I'm intrigued that OP can blithely assert *they are slightly different in meaning (when we are translating them).* Quite apart from the fact that I don't see any semantic distinction *myself*, I can't see how OP can know to translate them differently.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've done my best to measure the delay that follows each...I'll concede that it's neck and neck

Comment: @Ronald Sole: I'm not sure which is the more dated/poetic element here -  the use of ***no sooner*** rather than ***hardly***, or the subject/verb inversion entailed in "fronting" the adverb to *no sooner **had I** [blah blah]*. But in most real-world natural contexts, I'm sure *I'd **only just** [blah blah]* would be far more common today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not sure about poetic but the issue might be that I'm getting a bit dated myself. Will google it!

Comment: @Ronald Sole: Assuming that was a case of [*No sooner said than done*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22No+sooner+said+than+done%22), did you discover anything?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I discovered that it's hazardous to express a view that one cannot argue convincingly.

Comment: Would it not depend on the language you are translating to? If it has expressions for the same nuances that "hardly" and "no sooner" differ with, then there might not be any problem.

Comment: What are you translating into?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I asked about their difference in translating because of my not-native origin. It is probably the only reason why you are wondering about it while I'm looking for the answer.

Comment: @Peter, From Ukrainian into English. I think it might be the reason my question boils down to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"No sooner" tells us that an action was completed and then something followed shortly after.  It emphasizes the immediacy with which the the second action followed the first.

"Hardly" suggests that the second action interrupted the first, or very nearly did.  It hints at a lack of completion or a very near inability to complete it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might help.

Some alternatives, in order of least to greatest amount of time between *arriving* and *raining*, might be

> They had **no sooner** arrived *when* it began to rain.
>
> **Just when** they arrived, it began to rain.
>   They **had just** arrived *when* it began to rain.
>
> They **had hardly** arrived *when* it began to rain.
>   They **had barely** arrived *when* it began to rain.
>
> **Upon** their arrival, it began to rain.
>
> **After** they arrived, it began to rain.